# Customize toolbar in xlviewer.aspx

Tags: excel-services

We would like to replace the "Open in Excel" button with the "Download a snapshot" command in the xlviewer.aspx file. Is this something you can configure when using this file to view documents?

I have read that it may be possible to customize the Excel Services web part, but for this we would presumably have to replace xlviewer.aspx? If we did this, is it possible to alter the behaviour of "AllItems.aspx" so that when clicking an excel file, it uses the new viewer file, and not the old one?

Comment: Did you find an answer? We need to do this too. Thanks.